# Code to lock keyboard and mouse

Tags: c++, windows, vb.net, stack-overflow, vb.net-2010

Im actually starting on my final year project. And I am really appreciate the helps from u guys. It goes like this.
I want my application to remind the computer users that their computer screen will be locked out in 3 minutes and then lock their keyboard and mouse immediately so they are unable to do work on that period of time.
Anyone can help me with the codes to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: under a giggle I must ask, is this to punish those people forgetting to logout of their PC themselves? because forcing them to look at their screen for 3 minutes before it logs out automaticly is... well time wasted. So why not log them out directly?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link for intercepting the Keyboard events. [low-level-keyboard-hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076060/low-level-keyboard-hook-keystrokes-from-rawinput) If I remember right, you can tell the API you handled the keyboard event which will prevnet it from being passed on to the rest of the programs.  Not sure about the mouse events, I have to assume there is an API for that as well.

You should be able to look into Windows Messaging APIs as well to subscribe to the message service but not sure that you can prevent them from going to the rest of your applications.